# SQL Get data with territory 62 and 69 but not in territory 200 and 92

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to grab data that have territory 62 and 69 but that do not have territory 200 and 92 , I am using this query  but that doesn't work

```
select  rtp1.releaseId, rtp1.territoryId
from ReleaseTerritoryPrice rtp1
where rtp1.territoryId  in (62,69)
  and not exists (select releaseId
                  from ReleaseTerritoryPrice t2
                  where t2.territoryId in (200,92)
                    and rtp1.releaseId = t2.releaseId);
```

Any Help ?
Thanks.

Comment: In what way is this failing to work? Is it returning releaseIds that are in territory 200 or 92? Is it failing to return releaseIds that are in territory 62 or 69, but not in 200 or 92? Is it producing an error? Do you want it to exclude **only** those releaseIds that are in **both** 200 and 92?

Comment: What format is the data in territoryId? At first sight, if it's 62 or 69, then it can't be 200 or 92.

Comment: @nurdglaw: apparently, `releaseId` is not a unique key.  The original query should work, but the requirements are somewhat vague and need further explanation - as MarkBannister has mentioned.

Comment: @PinnyM, right, gotcher thanks. It's my old problem - I see a column called id and assume it's, an id. Sigh, when will I learn? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a set-within-sets query.  I like to use aggregation with a having clause for this, because this is a very flexible approach:

```
select ReleaseId
from ReleaseTerritoryPrice
group by ReleaseId
having (sum(case when territoryId = 62 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
        sum(case when territoryId = 69 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
       ) and
       (sum(case when territoryId = 200 then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
        sum(case when territoryId = 92 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
       )
```

Each condition in the `having` clause is counting the number of rows with each of the territories.  The first two are saying that `62` and `69` must be present (the counts are greater than 1).  The last two are saying that `200` and `92` are not present (the counts are 0).

As an example, if you wanted to change this so that only one of `62` and `69` were needed but not the other two, the `having` clause would be:

```
having (sum(case when territoryId = 62 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
        sum(case when territoryId = 69 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
       ) and
       (sum(case when territoryId = 200 then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
        sum(case when territoryId = 92 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
       )
```

Comment: Hmm, but this won't return the territories that are actually associated - can you return this without another join?

Comment: @PinnyM . . . If you want the territories, then you need to join back to the original table.