# SQL query is taking more than 10 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The following query is taking too much time (more than 10 minutes). Is there a way to make it faster?

```
select  r.id,rs1.Id,  rs2.Id
  from Resource rs1 , Resource rs2 , ResourceTerritory rst1 ,
 ResourceTerritory rst2 ,
 ReleaseResource rr1 , 
 ReleaseResource rr2 , Release r
 where
rs1.Id=rst1.ResourceId and rs2.Id=rst2.ResourceId and rs1.Id=rr1.ResourceId and rs2.Id=rr2.ResourceId
and rr1.ReleaseId=rr2.ReleaseId 
and rs1.Id<>rs2.id
and rs1.OwningTerritoryId=69 and rs2.OwningTerritoryId=200
and r.Id=rr1.ReleaseId and r.OwningTerritoryId=69 and rs1.IsLocked=0 and rs2.IsLocked=0
group by   r.id,rs1.Id,  rs2.Id
having SUM( case when rst1.TerritoryId = 62 then 1 else 0 end)>0 and 
SUM( case when rst1.TerritoryId = 69 then 1 else 0 end)>0 and
SUM( case when rst1.TerritoryId = 200 then 1 else 0 end)>0 and 
SUM( case when rst1.TerritoryId = 201 then 1 else 0 end)>0 and
SUM( case when rst2.TerritoryId = 69 then 1 else 0 end)>0  and 
SUM( case when rst2.TerritoryId = 62 then 1 else 0 end)>0  and 
SUM( case when rst2.TerritoryId = 200 then 1 else 0 end)>0  and 
SUM( case when rst2.TerritoryId = 201 then 1 else 0 end)=0
```

Comment: It is impossible to say while we can not look at query execution plan.  You can get it use SET STATISTICS XML ON option. CREATE TABLE statements (with INDEX-es) will be usefull.

Comment: Yes, find a way to get rid of the SUM's in the having clause. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Indexes ? Table cardinality ? Your own ideas about what could be affecting performance ? Simpler queries to search for the "slow" clause or set of clauses ? In a word, what have you tried ? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: That's nice, if you want a decent answer we need the query execution plan and the indexes on all of those tables (as an absolute minimum). The relevant parts of the tables DDL would be better as would a rough idea of the selectivity of all the columns you're using and the number of rows in the table.

Comment: For starters, please convert your comma and Where based joins to proper JOINs so that sql server can correctly determine the structure of the query and optimise appropriately. Secondly, on your HAVING you can make it more like `SUM( case when rst1.TerritoryId in( 62, 69, 200) or rst2.TerritoryId in( 62, 69, 200) then 1 else 0 end)> 0 ` Please repost an updated query so the JOINs can be evaluated.

Comment: Are you going to keep mangling and torturing your proposed *solutions* to your problem, or could you not ask a question that presents the *data* you have and clearly state the result that you're *seeking*? This is the *fifth* question on this same problem, by my count.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Get data with territory 62 and 69 but not in territory 200 and 92](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966416/sql-get-data-with-territory-62-and-69-but-not-in-territory-200-and-92)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have indexes on (e.g.) **TerritoryId**?

Also check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345434.aspx

and run SQL Server Profiler (under Tools-menu)

And instead of the `WHERE` clause you can use the `INNER JOIN` clause

Answer (score 0):

```
having SUM( case when rst1.TerritoryId = 62 then 1 else 0 end)>0 and 
SUM( case when rst1.TerritoryId = 69 then 1 else 0 end)>0 and
SUM( case when rst1.TerritoryId = 200 then 1 else 0 end)>0 and 
SUM( case when rst1.TerritoryId = 201 then 1 else 0 end)>0 and
SUM( case when rst2.TerritoryId = 69 then 1 else 0 end)>0  and 
SUM( case when rst2.TerritoryId = 62 then 1 else 0 end)>0  and 
SUM( case when rst2.TerritoryId = 200 then 1 else 0 end)>0  and 
SUM( case when rst2.TerritoryId = 201 then 1 else 0 end)=0
```

Should be replaced by

```
WHERE 
(rst1.TerritoryId = 62 
OR rst1.TerritoryId = 69 
OR rst1.TerritoryId = 200 
OR rst1.TerritoryId = 201) 
AND 
(rst2.TerritoryId = 62 
OR rst2.TerritoryId = 69 
OR rst2.TerritoryId = 200 
)
```

Comment: Hello thanks for that , I actually need that the territory for rst1 to be 62 and 69 and 200 and 201 and for rst2 to be 62 and 69 and 200 but not 201.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this -

```
SELECT  r.ID
        ,rs1.ID
        ,rs2.ID 
FROM dbo.Release r
JOIN dbo.[Resource] rs1 ON r.ID = rr1.ReleaseId AND rs1.IsLocked = 0
JOIN dbo.ResourceTerritory rst1 ON rs1.ID = rst1.ResourceId
JOIN dbo.[Resource] rs2 ON rs2.IsLocked = 0
JOIN dbo.ResourceTerritory rst2 ON rs2.ID = rst2.ResourceId
JOIN dbo.ReleaseResource rr1 ON rs1.ID = rr1.ResourceId 
JOIN dbo.ReleaseResource rr2 ON rr1.ReleaseId = rr2.ReleaseId
WHERE rs2.ID = rr2.ResourceId
    AND rs1.ID <> rs2.ID
    AND rs1.OwningTerritoryId = 69
    AND rs2.OwningTerritoryId = 200
    AND r.OwningTerritoryId = 69
    AND rst1.TerritoryId IN (62, 69 , 200 , 201) 
    AND rst2.TerritoryId IN (62 , 69 , 200 , 201)
GROUP BY
    r.ID
    ,rs1.ID
    ,rs2.ID
```

Comment: @saadamiens. Sorry, but your query a silent horror :(

Comment: hello , rst1.territory id must have 62 and 69 and 200 and 201 and for rst2.territory it must have 62 and 69 and 200 but not 201